# what is the name of the molecule that has the greatest number of different atoms?

Tags: molecules

What is the name of the molecule that has the greatest number of different kinds of atoms?

For example, H2O is water has 2 different kinds of atoms which are H and O.

For example, C6H12O6 is fructose and has 3 different kinds of atoms which are C, H and O.

After warned to be a too broad question. I will rephrase it. The molecule must be stable and can be find in nature.

what is the name of the molecule has the record?

Comment: I'm sure that the first question people will ask is "in a theoretical sense or in reality?".

Comment: This question could have an interesting answer, but it's quite hard to define the limits that would make it interesting. For a sufficiently large molecule, you could fit just about anything in the periodic table somewhere in it. Throw a ton of different compounds in a flask containing every element, find a crazy way to cross-polymerize and coordinate everything, and you could obtain a mess composed of gigantic molecules, at least one of which would be statistically expected to contain at least one atom of each element (with the possible exception of some noble gasses).

Comment: Actually, if you attached [endohedral fullerene compounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endohedral_fullerene), even helium and neon would make it into a molecule. In fact you could likely encapsulate any atom or small molecules containing any atom, then attach the fullerenes onto a polymer backbone.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is answerable since I'm not sure anyone keeps track of this "record". It would have to be a biological molecule. For example, if we consider [chromatin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatin)(the DNA-histone complex that makes up chromosomes) to be a single molecule, we would have (so long as we did not forget the various possible counterions) a molecule with $\ce{C,H,N,O,P,S,Cl,Na,K,Ca,Mg}$.

Comment: What about metallic bonding. I'm sure we can just dump a bunch of metals to form some sort of super alloy